# How to extract/parse the binary content from a Multipart response in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multipartform-data, multipart

I want to extract the binary content from a multipart response that I have as follows -
[image: Multipart Response]

I do not have access to any request object (Express/NodeJS). I just have this response object which I want to parse and extract the binary part of it.

**EDIT** -

To make things more clear -

1. I have an endpoint (Not a traditional Express app but FaaS) - called "/fileUpload"
2. This endpoint accepts all kind of requests - GET, POST, PUT (FaaS).
3. When I make a POST/PUT request with a file - `testImage.PNG` in the form data, I receive the content in the request object. FaaS runtime provides the req object as a function handler's parameter.
4. Now, when I print - request.body of the incoming POST request, I get the content as show in the image above.
5. If I try to upload this binary content directly to S3, it leads to corruption of the image which I believe is due to the presence of additional content in the multipart response like - `Content-Disposition`...

What I would like to do is, parse the additional multipart content like the Content-Type header and multipart boundary etc, so that I get only the image binary.

Comment: This looks like a file upload of a file named `testImage.PNG`. Do you want to store the file in your server's filesystem? Place it in an array? Or what?  Please [edit] your question to clarify your requirement.

Answer (score 3):

To extract the binary content, we need to remove/parse the header and boundary sections of it. There exists a library - [parse-multipart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-multipart) which makes it easy to do so.

Example -

Assuming request header contains a `content-type` header.

```
var multipart = require('parse-multipart');
// The following section is the express endpoint/ FaaS handler
    {

        let header = req.headers["content-type"]
        let boundary  = header.split(" ")[1]
        boundary = header.split("=")[1]
        let body = event.data;
        //console.log("Boundary - "+ boundary)
        let parts = multipart.Parse(body, boundary);
        for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            var part = parts[i];
            console.log(part)

            var params = {
                Bucket: s3bucket,
                Key: part.file,
                Body: part.data,
                ACL: 'public-read',
                Metadata: {
                    'Content-Type': part.type
                }
            };
            //Upload the data to aws
            const data = await s3.putObject(params).promise()


        }
        return parts

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I struggled for many days with this problem. The solution was in the **API GATE WAY** > **configuration** > **Binary types**  add `multipart/form-data`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

***Observation on parse-multipart library***: Be warned, this does not provide the 'name' directive of the multi-part body.

The documentation is very sketchy, reporting of error, really is not there.
Apparently valid multi-part body is not parsed and the reason would not be made clear by the library.

For more compliant processing, the libraries listed in the following URL could be considered:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser